# boost/geometry.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, boost, compilation, ubuntu-12.04, boost-geometry

I am trying to compile a c-extension for ruby.  It requires the boost libraries.

I ran `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` (which supposedly installs the boost libraries), but when I try to run `make` on the extension library I get `boost/geometry.hpp: No such file or directory`.  On my MacBook pro I was able to get everything working with homebrew and `brew install boost`.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Is there some other configuration I need to expose the headers to my c-extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `libboost-all-dev` doesn't include headers for some reason.  Once I compiled and installed boost from source my tool worked.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to re-configure after the installation of boost, to have the right includes in make. Try:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
```